# Splitting string with a struc

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split

I have a list with following structure.

```py
list = ['FUTSTKBHEL27-AUG-2020','FUTSTKBERGEPAINT27-AUG-2020']
```

I want to break each string into 3 part: 'FUTSTK', Date( variable but always has 11 lengths) and whatever remains in the middle( can have any number of alphabets)

eg:'FUTSTKBHEL27-AUG-2020' = 'FUTSTK','BHEL','27-AUG-2020

'FUTSTKBERGEPAINT27-AUG-2020'='FUTSTK','BERGEPAINT','27-AUG-2020

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FUTSTK` is a constant that's always there in the string,

```
list=['FUTSTKBHEL27-AUG-2020','FUTSTKBERGEPAINT27-AUG-2020']
print([('FUTSTK',x[6:-11], x[-11:]) for x in list])
```

Output:

```
[('FUTSTK', 'BHEL', '27-AUG-2020'), ('FUTSTK', 'BERGEPAINT', '27-AUG-2020')]
```